# How to get absolute path of a view in android?

Tags: android, view

Recently, I am working on a android project needing that view's absolute path.

For example, a button_0 in LinearLayout

The absolute path of button_0 is

"DecorView>LinearLayout[0]>FrameLayout[1]>RelativeLayout[0]>Button[0]":"button_0"

How could I get this absolute path automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep going up in views with something like this:

```
Button startingButton = findViewById(R.id.startingButton);
ViewParent v = startingButton.getParent();
while(v != null) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(v.getId()) + " : " + v.getClass().getName());
    v = v.getParent();
}
```

That'll get you all of the IDs and the class names ("android.widget.ImageView", for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot. but  `View v = startingButton.getParent();` should be `ViewParent v = startingButton.getParent();`